# Can a rational map be extended without using resolution of indeterminacies?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have a finite morphism C --> D, where C is an open subvariety of some projective variety C' and D is open in D', also projective.  Thus there is a rational map from C' to D'.  Is there a way to extend this to a finite morphism without resolving indeterminacies?  That is, is there a natural morphism from C' to D' (or to any other variety) that agrees with C --> D when restricted to C?

Comment: Isn't finding such a morphism exactly "resolving indeterminacies"? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Take an arbitrary projective birational morphism $f:D'\to C'$ and let $C\subseteq C'$ be an open set such that $f\left|_{f^{-1}(C)}\right.: f^{-1}(C)\to C$ is an isomorphism. Let $D=f^{-1}(C)$. Then there is an isomorphism $C\to D$ which you cannot extend to a morphism $C'\to D'$ without doing something to $C'$. Of course, there is an "extension" of that isomorphism to the identity $C'\to C'$. As for "to any other variety", perhaps you should make it more precise what you mean.

Comment: If C were closed in Y, and C --> D were a finite morphism, then one could form the universal pushout and Y would go to some X.  In this case, C is open in C' and C --> D is a finite morphism.  I don't think the pushout works for an open immersion C --> C'.  However if one were dealing with analytic spaces then one could extend the morphism C --> D --> D' to C' by looking at limit points.  I'm wondering if there is some other way to extend the morphism C --> D to a morphism C' --> D' without blowing up something in C' (which would necessarily be outside of C).

Comment: I should say, to extend C --> D to some morphism C' --> D'' where the target is specified only to contain D.

Comment: Limits don't work, because they're not unique. Think of a blow-up. A point might have to be mapped to a higher dimensional object, that's why you need a resolution. If you do a push-out, that will contract the locus where the indeterminacy should map, so for instance in the example above, you will get the identity map $C'\to C'$.